# Double integral exercise - check answer

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate

$$\mathop{\iint}_{R} (x^2 + y^2) \,dx \,dy $$

where $R$ is the region (in the plane) bounded by
the lines $y=x$, $x=2$ and the hyperbola $xy=1$.

To calculate this integral I broke $R$ into two regions.

$R_1:0 \le x \le 1,   0 \le y \le x$

$R_2:1 \le x \le 2,   0 \le y \le 1/x$

And I calculated the integral of $(x^2 + y^2)$ over both of them.

At the end I got this answer 47/24
but my book says the answer is 27/8

Which one is correct?

Comment: Why the integral over $R_1$?

Comment: Yeah there is a problem with using $x\in[0,1)$ since there is an obvious bounded region $x\in[1,2]$ but we have no boundary at $x=0.$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives me $27/8,$ when restricted to $x\in[1,2].$

Comment: Your region $R_1$ assumes implicitly that there is a boundary line at $y=0.$

Comment: And $R_2$ should be the region $x\in[1,2], y\in[1/x,x].$

Comment: Essentially, you've assumed the region is $x\in[0,2],$ $y\in[0,\min(x,1/x)].$ But that isn't the region given by the three curves. The three curves meat at $(1,1),$ $(2,1/2)$ and $(2,2).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I saw you posted a correct answer and deleted. Why did you delete?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I assumed a wrong region, it seems. That's right. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidP Wasn't sure the question showed enough work, so I deleted it. Rereading, it seems to qualify - an edit added some work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misread or misunderstood the region.

The three curves meet, pairwise, at three points, $(1,1),$ $(2,1/2),$ and $(2,2).$ The region is like a triangle on those three points, but with the path from $(1,1)$ to $(2,1/2)$ a curve.

In particular, $y\geq \frac12$ inside $R.$

The correct integral is:

$$\int_1^2 \int_{1/x}^x(x^2+y^2)\,dy\,dx$$

This becomes $$\int_1^2\left(x^3-x+\frac13\left(x^3-x^{-3}\right)\right)\,dx$$

You can go from here.